# Remove tr elements class

Tags: javascript, css, class, extjs, tr

How can I remove a class that is defined to a table row element using EXT JS or plain Javascript. The class I want to remove is `x-grid-row-selected` 
Using `tr.removeCls('x-grid-row-selected)` gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableRowElement> has no method 'removeCls'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext provides a [removeCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-removeCls) method but you need an instance of an Ext Element for it to work.  HTMLElement does not have a removeCls method that is why you are getting the error.  This should work:

```
Ext.fly(tr).removeCls('x-grid-row-selected')
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $("tr").removeClass('x-grid-row-selected);
    });
```

Comment: Does it says anwhere that I want to use jQuery

Comment: No need to get blunt when someone is trying to help. @srinu-m, mind elaborating what exactly the code is doing?